# Is it correct to use Celery in Kafka Consumer?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, celery, kafka-consumer-api

I am doing some long-running tasks in Kafka Consumer. I want to know that I am doing right or wrong? I am using Kafka Consumer to consumer messages from another server and messages are processing as I want. I am putting the received message in the Celery queue. And all is working well. Does Here need Celery? Or Kafka will handle it as a queuing system?

```
_consumer = KafkaConsumer(KAFKA_TOPIC, bootstrap_servers=['{}:{}'.format(HOST, PORT)],auto_offset_reset="earliest", value_deserializer=lambda x: ReadHelper().json_deserializer(x), group_id="mygroupZ1")
    
    for msg in _consumer:

        payload = msg.value

        print("data fetched payload------------------")
        long_running_task.delay(payload) # Does here need Celery task to put in?
```

Answer (score 0):

Kafka consumers need to periodically poll Kafka. If you run some blocking function, then it'll eventually stop that consumer and rebalance the consumer group, then maybe will restart unless another consumer takes over. Therefore, if queues are local in memory, it's not guaranteed that consumer will be processing the data it had just consumed. In other words, if a rebalance happened, you could process duplicate events.

Otherwise, if you push onto a different queue, delay that event, then don't wait, you run the risk of overwhelming that queue, and you need to implement backpressure, e.g. `_consumer.pause()` and wait for the queue to drain, then resume polling from Kafka. You also have no way of managing Kafka record offsets, such as determining queue process failures, so there's a potential for lost data as it's just "fire and forget"